# Changing product image colors

Tags: image, magento-1.9

I have a product with say 4 different pieces, like a shirt. The sleeves, the collar, the buttons, the body of the shirt are available in different colors. Each piece can be a different color. So with 20 + colors I would like to have a product image that would reflect a potential customer desire to have the pieces in the color or colors they might select...Any ideas? Making individual images of all the potential color combinations and using swatches is just not practical. Open to ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think making individual images of all the potential color combinations and using swatches is a good choice. 
The basic combination is all different pieces in one color. 
Other new combination should based on "ton sur ton" concept, it means that all items have to in same tone color. 
For example: https://www.ostraining.com/cdn/images/magento/images/swatch-images-magento.png

Comment: Thank you but swatches are not an option if you have a 7 part item with almost 30 different available colors for each part...that would mean creating a unique image for each potential color combination..